# $_POST Is empty after submit on simple HTML + PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm testing some beginners features here and am having some difficulties on checking the $_POST content.

What am I missing here?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="post.php" method="post" >
            First Number: <input type="text" id="n1" name="n1"> <br> Second Number: <input type="text" id="n2" name="n2" onblur="calcular()"/> <br>
            <input type="text" id="resultado" name="resultado">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function calcular() {
        var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value, 10);
        var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').value, 10);
        var result = n1 + n2;
        document.getElementById('resultado').value = result;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is post.php:

```
 <?php   
        
       echo "<pre>"; 
       var_dump($_POST);
       echo "</pre>";

        
        
        ?>
```

Comment: Check the DevTools Network tab to see what's being sent when you submit the form.

Comment: Give a name to your form.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Are you sure that your file post.php is in the same place as the html you are running? (ie are you sure it's being run at all?)